Generating polar lot with specific gridlines with rectangular appearance with matplotlib
I want to generate a similar plot like this  Right now, I want to generate an emplty polar plot with the exact grid lines as in the image and with angle ticks like this one: . How to generate the grid and ticks?
I have searched the interned, but I am completely at a loss on how to do this.

Maybe Focus on specific lon/lat using spstere projection gives some starting ideas?

what is the best that you can do so far ?  no attempt has been made . . .

yep, no attempt has been made because i did not know where to start
